# Running a first differenced model that accounts for time fixed effects

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel database and I would like to run a dynamic model that accounts for both unit and time fixed effects. For reason related to the structure of the panel, I want to run a model in first differences. Would this model make sense?

[image]

Where the unit fixed effects are subsumed by the annual differences. The [image] is the first difference of my dependent variable, [image] is the first difference of my exogenous regressors.

My question is on the correct way to account for time fixed effects: [image] is the first difference of the time dummies. Is this the correct way to do this or there are other more appropriate ways?

Thanks a lot for your help

best